# Ignore round brackets of strings when comparing CSV files

Tags: powershell

I am trying to compare the string of two CSV files. If the string from the 2nd CSV file occurs in the 1st CSV file, the corresponding line in the 1st CSV file should be marked with a label (e.g.: "TestLabel") after the semicolon. The strings contain a lot of special characters. By and large, the comparison already works, I can also already add the label. But I have the problem that some strings contain a round bracket and with these it does not work - I get no result and also no error message.

CSV1 contains:

```
Testdefinition;Stichwörter;Stichwörter;Stichwörter;Stichwörter;Stichwörter
It is just a normal text (with round brackets).Test: success;ExistingLabel;;;;
This is a second text;;;
Another text;ExistingLabel;;;;
One more text for the testing - success;ExistingLabel;;;;
```

CSV2 contains:

```
Testdefinition;Stichwörter;Stichwörter;Stichwörter;Stichwörter;Stichwörter
It is just a normal text (with round brackets).Test: success
One more text for the testing - success
```

My script so far:

```
$header='Testdefinition', 'Stichwörter1', 'Stichwörter2', 'Stichwörter3', 'Stichwörter4', 'Stichwörter5'
$exportheader="Testdefinition;Stichwörter;Stichwörter;Stichwörter;Stichwörter;Stichwörter"

$path1='D:\data\.....test.csv'
$path2='D:\data\.....test_failed.csv'

$wfile='temp1.csv'
$wfile2='temp2.csv'

Get-Content $path1 | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content $wfile -Encoding UTF8
Get-Content $path2 | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content $wfile2 -Encoding UTF8

$file1=Import-CSV -Path $wfile -Delimiter ";" -Header $header
$file2=Import-CSV -Path $wfile2 -Delimiter ";" -Header $header


$exportfile='test.csv'
#$exportfile=$file1

$file1 | Get-Member
$file2 | Get-Member

$file1 | Format-Table
$file2 | Format-Table

Write-Output ""
Write-Output "Searching for failed results"

Set-Content $exportfile -Value $exportheader

$file1.Testdefinition | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output "The Testdefinition is: $_ "
    $testSearch = $_

    $testlinecontent = $file2.Testdefinition | Select-String $testSearch
    $testlinenumber = $testlinecontent.LineNumber

    if("$_" -eq "$testlinecontent")
    {
        Write-Output "Testline found: $testlinecontent in Line $testlinenumber"
        Write-Output "$_ = $testlinecontent"

        

        $testlineexport = "$_;$testlinenumber;TestLabel"

        Write-Output $testlineexport

        $testlineexport | Add-Content -Path $exportfile
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Output "Testline not found"
        $testlineexport = "$_;$testlinenumber;NULL"

        Write-Output $testlineexport
        $testlineexport | Add-Content -Path $exportfile
    }

    Write-Output ""
}

$exportCsv = Import-Csv $exportfile -Delimiter ";" -Header $header
$exportCsv | Format-Table

Remove-Item -Path $wfile
Remove-Item -Path $wfile2
```

I hope you can give me a hint. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `Select-String $testSearch -SimpleMatch` because you don't want regex validation in this case

Comment: Please don't ask what is in essence the same question multiple times. Instead, engage with those who have already provided feedback and / or consider ways of improving your question to enable others to help you more easily. See also: [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon sorry for my late answer but thank you very very much! Your answer is very helpful :)